# Transporting Pothos Cuttings

Tags: houseplants, cuttings

I'm looking to transport some cuttings of a healthy Pothos plant (Marble Queen cultivar). I know that rooted Pothos can do ridiculous things like survive in darkness, but I don't know how hardy the cuttings are. The question: what is the safest way to transport a cutting of Pothos in airline luggage?